# What does the 'FX' in 'JavaFX' stand for?

Tags: javafx, naming

I am currently writing a text about JavaFX and tried to find references what the 'FX' actually stands for.

I found some discussions to whether it might mean ['Effects'](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_24577348.html) or ['nothing particular at all'](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1141700). But no clear statement.

**Are there references to what the 'FX' in 'JavaFX' really stands for?**

Comment: Its just a name. FX is normally related with `sound or visual effects`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely it stands for Java "special EFF-ECTS" as FX is normally the abbreviation given to special effects mostly sound or visual.

You can also refer this article: [What Do All the Words in a JavaFX App Mean?](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-do-all-the-words-in-a-javafx-app-mean.html)

Comment: And `FX` is a common abbreviation of special effects: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_effect

Comment: The article you linked is not so certain that this is what FX *really* stands for: `... and JavaFX probably has something to with Java "special EFF-ECTS`

Comment: @Aerus:- Hope now the edit makes the answer a suitable one and less contradictory!

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that the original software was named F3 (Form Follows Function), I would suppose it's something like Java (F)orm E(X)perience...

Comment: Do you have any sources you could provide? Or is this a guess?

Comment: Just a guess... But thinking again, maybe "Form Follows Function" has a deeper meaning. Chris Oliver knows for sure, he was the creator and the head of the project in Oracle...

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is no longer in the standard Java release as of java 11. It is now OpenJFX

According to this [OpenJFX 11 introduction](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) it would seem the name is related to FXML,"FXML is a scriptable, XML-based markup language for constructing Java object graphs" so it could refer to both special effects and fxml.

Answer (score -2):

Java FX menas Java + **F**lash + fle**X**

Which can be used to do annimation and effects. Java fx is also a rich web client.

Comment: Do you have sources for the claim "Java FX menas Java + Flash + fleX" ?